# Declare variable to function without running it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def user(choose):
    if (choose == "1"):
        play = game()
    elif (choose == "2"):
        return stats(play)
    else:
        return quit()
```

I want to take the value from function game() and use it in stats(), but I get an error saying that play is not defined. How do I declare game() and use it in another function?

Comment: What do you mean? If you don't run the function it can't return anything... (or do 
 *anything* for that matter)

Comment: a function "runs". That's its job. you want a function that knows what to return but skips over all the lines before returning a value? That is....strange, and very...unfunctionlike. what is the point of "code" in function1 then? Can it even be done? No, a function will evaluate things and cannot return results until it runs.

Comment: Check if this is not a so called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I was not clear. I've updated the post

Comment: Hi Gringo, when you fix your questions, try to keep as much as possible from original, just keep adding "clarifications". Otherwise comments/answers for future readers look really strange.

Answer (score 1):

You could "postpone" execution of `func1`:

```
def func1():
    return 'abc'

def something_else(callable):
    callable()

def main():
    hello = None

    def f():
        """set result of func1 to variable hello"""
        nonlocal hello
        hello = func1()

    # over here func1 is not executed yet, hello have not got its value
    # you could pass function f to some other code and when it is executed, 
    # it would set result for hello 
    print(str(hello))  # would print "None"
    call_something_else(f)
    print(str(hello))  # would print "abc"

main()
```

After question has changed...

Right now, your local variable `play` is out of scope for stats.
Also, looks like you expect that function would be called twice.
You need to save `play` in global content

```
play = None  # let's set it to some default value
def user(choose):
    global play  # let python know, that it is not local variable

    if choose == "1":  # no need for extra brackets
        play = game()

    if choose == "2" and play:  # double check that play is set
        return stats(play)

    return quit()
```